# How to create a @Version decorator in nestjs at http method level?

Tags: node.js, server, nestjs, typescript-decorator

Given a snippet of code following standard approach to set a controller.

```
@Get('/first')
getAll() {
  // Some logic here!
}
```

This can be accessed by `/api/products/first`

Can we create a decorator that can do the following?

```
@Version(2)
@Get('/first')
getAll() {
  // Some logic here!
}
```

Now I should be able to access this through `/api/products/v2/first`

Or

```
@Version([1,2])
@Get('/first')
getAll() {
  // Some logic here!
}

@Version([3])
@Get('/first')
getAllv3() {
  // Some logic here!
}
```

Allowing usage of `/api/products/v1/first`, `/api/products/v2/first` and `/api/products/v3/first`.
Tried using SetMetaData but that how to edit a route that is already defined or to be defined.
I am stuck. Please Help.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible without a lot of work as you would have to handle a big part of the routing yourself. You could use `@Get('/v2/first')` which isn' really clean though.

Comment: @sandrooco Is it possible to use this.reflector inside a custom decorator. If thats possible I think we can use setMetaData to set version number and custom get decorator to do get with a different route.

Comment: I honestly don't know, you could try it though!

Comment: It is potentially easier to just have 2 controllers. user-v1.controller.ts and user-v2.controller.ts with different `@Controller` mappings for your versioning. You could also look at using https://github.com/nestjsx/nest-router to declare your routes and set up URL versioning

Comment: @Nikhil.Nixel - did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @rgwozdz latest version of nestjs already has this feature built in, refer docs here https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning#versioning